# Excel VBA sheet copy command doesn't work on function

Tags: excel, vba

I want to define a formula with a VBA function to copy the sheet. When I use the copy command inside `Sub` everything is done correctly, but when I want to use the function it doesn't work!
This is my code:

```
Sub sub1()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=Worksheets("Sheet1")
End Sub

Function function1()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=Worksheets("Sheet1")
End Function
```

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: Why do u need a `formula` to copy a sheet?

Comment: Try to type the function e.g. ```Function f1() As Boolean``` and return ```true``` after your line.

Comment: VBA functions called from a worksheet are restricted in what they can do. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel-f2f0ce5d-8ea5-6ce7-fddc-79d36192b7a1#:~:text=A%20user%2Ddefined%20function%20called%20by%20a%20formula%20in%20a%20worksheet%20cell%20cannot%20change%20the%20environment%20of%20Microsoft%20Excel.%20This%20means%20that%20such%20a%20function%20cannot%20do%20any%20of%20the%20following%3A

Answer (score 0):

A sub routine is for performing operations, which could include copying and pasting, but could also include analysing information and finding an answer.  A function is for analysing data and returning an answer.

It is good coding to restrict how you use these code types, it will make your code easier to read by other people for one thing.  On the part of microsoft, it  prevents their software products from crashing if they set a few strict code rules.  To give an example, functions can be run from within spreadsheet cells, and hence every time a spreadsheet cell is edited, the function code will run, and these could create an endless loop if the function code started altering other parts of a worksheet or workbook that was set to autocalculate; but if the function does not allow other parts of the spreadsheet to be edited, then it prevents that problem from occurring.

With your function, you are not seeking to return an answer, rather you are trying to manipulate the spreadsheet, which is more in the realm of subs, so there is no need to use function when sub will do.